# C strtok on global string from multiple functions

Tags: c, strtok

I use a global string that I want to parse. Parsing is done from multiple functions.
For example I extract first token in func1(), then second token from the same global string in func2() and etc...
Is this possible? I know that extraction of tokens after the first one is done by strtok(NULL,delimiter) and strtok saves the pointer to the next byte to the delimiter replaced with null, but I couldn't find the description how exactly the strtok saves the string it delimits when it's done in different functions.

Comment: Because you said "global string", make sure the string you are using `strtok` on is not a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

possible.
strtok saves the string to static memory.

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char sentence[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
char* sentencep = sentence;

char* func1(void){
    char* p = sentencep;
    if(sentencep != NULL)
        sentencep = NULL;
    return strtok(p, " ");
}

char* func2(void){
    char* p = sentencep;
    if(sentencep != NULL)
        sentencep = NULL;
    return strtok(p, " ");
}

int main(){
    puts(func1());//The
    puts(func2());//quick
    puts(func2());//brown
    puts(func1());//fox
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtok.c.htm